# Calculating probability of quantum measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-measurements

Consider the measurements of an observable $A$, with orthonormal eigenstates $$f_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\begin{bmatrix}
           {-i} \\
           {2} \\
           {1}
         \end{bmatrix},\enspace f_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}
           {-i} \\
           {-1} \\
           {1}
         \end{bmatrix},\enspace f_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
           {i} \\
           {0} \\
           {1}
         \end{bmatrix}$$

We are taking measurements of $A$ in the fixed state $$\psi_0=\begin{bmatrix}
           {1} \\
           {\sqrt{5}i} \\
           {2}
         \end{bmatrix}$$

We can now write $$\psi_0=c_1f_1+c_2f_2+c_3f_3$$

and the numbers $\vert c_i \vert^2$ correspond to specific probabilities. However I found that $$c_1=\langle f_1\vert\psi_0\rangle=\cdots\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(i+2\sqrt{5}i+2)$$

This is total nonsense. But I can't see where I made a mistake.

Comment: your $\psi_0$ is not normalized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense it's just not normalized. One way to fix this would be to just be to normalize $\psi_0$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \begin{bmatrix} {1} \\{\sqrt{5}i} \\ {2} \end{bmatrix}$, and then the inner products would all give normalized probability amplitudes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how normalizing the state is going to help

Comment: Let's compose the normalized $| \psi_0 \rangle$ into its components of the orthonormal eigenstates. $ \begin{align*} 
c_1 &= \langle f_1 | \psi_0 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{60}} (2+(2\sqrt{5}+1)i) \\
c_2 &= \langle f_2 | \psi_0 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{30}} (2+(1-\sqrt{5})i) \\
c_3 &=\langle f_3 | \psi_0 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{20}} (2-i) \\
|c_1|^2 &\approx 0.57 \\
|c_2|^2 &\approx 0.18 \\
|c_3|^2 &= 0.25\\
\end{align*}$.
These probability amplitudes sum to $1$ and "make sense".

Answer (score 0):

Here, the probability of measuring j is $\frac{|c_j|^2}{\sum_i^3 |c_i|^2}$.